# Independent rolls of a fair die

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, dice

> Question: Let $X$ denote the number of independent rolls of a fair die required to obtain the first $3$. What is $P(X \ge 6)$?

I think I have to get $3$ in $X$ rolls and I think I have to get $x$-$1$ non $3$'s first followed by a $3$. Am I correct with the approach? If so, then how do I compute this because I am struggling to find a way to do it properly. Need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that $X\geq 6$ is simply the probability of rolling something other than $3$ on the first five rolls. Thus, $\left(\frac56\right)^5$.

Does that makes sense?

---

Edit: You're right that $P(X=x)=(\frac56)^{x-1}(\frac16)$. If you sum that expression from $x=6$ to infinity, you end up with the same answer.

Comment: not totally because my question wants me to obtain the first $3$

Comment: Well, there are two possibilities: the first 3 occurs within the first five rolls, or it occurs after that. I.e., $X<6$, or $X\geq 6$. To find the probability of the second option, find the probability of NOT the first option.

Comment: For $X\geq 6$ you require non-3 in the first 5 rolls, then the first three on some roll after that. You don't care which. It could be the sixth, seventh, two thousand fourty second, or whatever; as long as it is not in the first five.  So $\mathsf P(X\geq 6)$ is the probability for five consecutive non-3 results.

Comment: Okay i see the logic @GTonyJacobs used.thanks

Comment: same answer as yours?

Comment: @behold, yes. Do you know how to do the geometric sum?

Comment: Not really. Dont remember

Comment: @behold Then it may be a good time to revise the Geometric Series, because, for some reason, that is related to the Geometric Distribution.  (Which is what you are dealing with here.)

Answer (score 1):

> I think I have to get x-1 non 3's first followed by a 3.

Almost! You don't include that last 3 because that would mean $X = x$, but we are interested in $X\geq x$, where $x = 6$. Notice instead that
$$\{X\geq6\}\iff\{ \text{The first five are not 3}\}.$$

This guarantees that the 3 will appear on the sixth roll or later.

Therefore $$P(X\geq 6) = P(\text{the first five are not 3}) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5.$$

Alternatively, notice that $X$ follows a geometric distribution with $p = 1/6$ on $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$.

Then we want
$$P(X\geq 6) = P\left(\bigcup_{k = 6}^\infty X = k\right) = \sum_{k = 6}^\infty P(X=k)$$
where we can sum because the events are disjoint. You can verify that they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on G Tony Jacobs' answer.

> I think I have to get $3$ in $X$ rolls and I think I have to get $x$-$1$ non $3$'s first followed by a $3$. Am I correct with the approach? If so, then how do I compute this because I am struggling to find a way to do it properly. Need help

Yes, $X$ is the count of tries until you obtain the first three. $X=x$ is the event of $x-1$ non-3 and then the first 3 on roll #$x$.

For the event of $X\geq 6$ you require non-3 in the first 5 rolls, then the first three on some roll after that. You don't care which. It could be the sixth, seventh, two thousand fourty second, or whatever; as long as it is not in the first five.

So $\mathsf P(X\geq 6)$ is the probability for obtaining five consecutive non-3 results, which is $(5/6)^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on G Tony Jacobs' answer mathematically,

The idea for answering this question boils down from [Geometric probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), wherein P(X>=6) means the probability that in order to obtain the first 3, at least 6 rolls in required.

Since X $\sim$ Geometric ($\frac{1}{6}$),

$$P(X \ge 6) = \sum_{k=6}^\infty (\frac{1}{6})(\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}$$

$$P(X \ge 6) = (\frac{1}{6}) \sum_{k=6}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}$$

Here, let $y = k-6$ , that means, $k = y+6$. So we can transform the above equation into:

$$P(X \ge 6) = (\frac{1}{6}) \sum_{y=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{y+5}$$

$$ = (\frac{1}{6}) (\frac{5}{6})^5 \sum_{y=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{y}$$

Here, the summation is nothing but of an infinite geometric progression, whose sum can be computed using [sum of infinite G.P](https://www.cuemath.com/infinite-geometric-series-formula/), that is,

$$ \sum_{y=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{y} = \frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})} = 6$$

So, $$P(X \ge 6) = (\frac{1}{6}) (\frac{5}{6})^5 (6) $$

$$P(X \ge 6) =  (\frac{5}{6})^5 $$

Hence, $$P(X \ge 6) \approx 0.4019   $$